# volley network image view and request headers

Tags: android, json, lotus-domino, android-volley

I have network image view which should get populated when I get the response back from the server in JSON format.

I get back a URL in json and I go to URL and show the image in my list view in android. However, this works fine if I use any image which is publicly hosted on internet.

In my case server is on IBM Domino and everything is in the domino database. The URL won't open unless i have user credentials to do so.

For general request responses using volley, I set a session ID in request headers, telling the domino server that i have authenticated myself already. however, in case of network Image view, I am unable to proceed as i do not know how to authenticate myself with the server.

The images do not show in the list view and I see following in my logcat

```
SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
```

I tried to open the same URL in browser, it asks for my user ID password and if I login, I am able to download the jpg file on my system.

Is there a way to set my http request headers for network image view ? How shall I proceed in this case ? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`NetworkImageView` uses [`ImageLoader`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/1ba6c2f2ba8fec62d6e5fc0fb20025f2c82bd728/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java) which internally makes [ImageRequests](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2afdd91aba3a7a5396fe96dfe8f930661e56ea9a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java) using `makeImageRequest`

[ImageRequest](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2afdd91aba3a7a5396fe96dfe8f930661e56ea9a/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java) extends from [Request](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/2afdd91aba3a7a5396fe96dfe8f930661e56ea9a/src/com/android/volley/Request.java). `Request` class has a `getHeaders()` method which allows to set request headers.

So if you can override `makeImageRequest` method of `ImageLoader` and then override `getHeaders()` for `ImageRequest` inside it, you should be able to set your request headers for `NetworkImageView`

```
@Override
protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight, final String cacheKey) {
    //return super.makeImageRequest(requestUrl, maxWidth, maxHeight, cacheKey);

    return new ImageRequest(requestUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response);
        }
    }, maxWidth, maxHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onGetImageError(cacheKey, error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", YOUR_TOKEN);
            return params;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: ok, so I shall write my own custom image loader and override makeImageRequest ?

Comment: give it a try. let's see how it goes

Comment: right now i am using this - mNetworkImageView.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, mImageLoader); ... Do I need to change this and use ImageRequest ?

Comment: Override makeImageRequest of mImageLoader - a custom image loader

Comment: yes, i did that, but how do I call it now. I have the custom class and i set the header, but how do i call this makeImageRequest ? Can you please provide some pseudo code ?

Comment: how do you instantiate mImageLoader? from volley singleton class? can you use your custom image loader there instead of image loader?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80374/discussion-between-random-and-k2ibegin).

Comment: if i just call the constructor of my image loader, then automatically override makeImageRequest will be called ? I tried with this, but images are still not loading !

Comment: can you come to chatroom?

Comment: click the link in 8th comment :)

Comment: onGetImageSuccess has private access in ImageLoader. What should I do, extend ImageLoader and make it not private?

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the above ImageLoader, but couldn't seem to override the `makeImageRequest` method.

When looking at the Volley implementation I couldn't see the same method signature, so I used the same approach by @random - here's my `CustomImageLoader`.

```
public class CustomImageLoader extends ImageLoader {

private Context mContext;

/**
 * Constructs a new ImageLoader.
 *
 * @param queue      The RequestQueue to use for making image requests.
 * @param imageCache The cache to use as an L1 cache.
 */
public CustomImageLoader(Context aContext, RequestQueue queue, ImageCache imageCache) {
    super(queue, imageCache);
    mContext = aContext;
}


@Override
protected Request<Bitmap> makeImageRequest(String requestUrl, int maxWidth, int maxHeight,
                                           ImageView.ScaleType scaleType, final String cacheKey,
                                           final ImageRequest.Transformation transformation) {

    return new ImageRequest(requestUrl, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
            onGetImageSuccess(cacheKey, response);
        }
    }, maxWidth, maxHeight, scaleType, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565, transformation, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            onGetImageError(cacheKey, error);
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return getHeaders(mContext); //*YOUR* method for getting headers

        }
    };

}
  }
```